# Best way to broadcast a live speach to web on local network

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, broadcast

I am looking for a kind of solutions to broadcast live speach from web to web or from a mobile app to web.

Person that makes the live speach will speak from his mobile on the web or on a app. listeners will  listen on web page without needing of an extra app etc.

Live speech sending and listining will be realized inside of a local network. And need a latency less than 1 second.

What can be different approches to solve this need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my researches best way is WebRTC.

As there will be more than 1 listener allways need a signal server or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is probably your best bet for low latency like that.

You don't need to implement it from scratch yourself. Have a look at https://www.vonage.co.uk/communications-apis/video/ and https://www.twilio.com/docs/video. They both provide services that are super simple to set up and require just a handful of HTML, CSS and JS to get going.